# django run localhost from another computer connected to another network

Tags: python, django, localhost

I am running my django project in localhost and it works fine..
For test purpose I want to run my localhost from another computer connected in the same network.

I have done `python manage.py runserver 'my ip address'`

That works fine too.. Is there any way that I can access my localhost from another computer connected to another network?

Like I am connected to A network and running my localhost and my friend is connected to B network. Suppose he wants to access my localhost and see my project running then is it possible to access localhost of a computer from another computer connected to another project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can. Just run the django runserver in

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now you can access your app using `youripaddress:8000`

From Django ...

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).
>
> You can provide an IPv6 address surrounded by brackets (e.g. [200a::1]:8000). This will automatically enable IPv6 support.

Updated:

In order to match the answer to Title of the question. You need configure your router to forward port 80 to yourapp address

Comment: then I can view my project in another computer conntected to another network ??

Comment: @VishnuRaj it'll available to your LAN network only.

Comment: @VishnuRaj Do you have router to forward port ( 8000 to your server ) then only you can access your localhost app from outside of the world .!

Comment: 'To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network,'... I can make my server viewable to other machines on the same network but I want it to make viewable to other machines on another network...

Comment: you need to tell the router to redirect requests via that 80 port to your computer’s local IP address.

Comment: @VishnuRaj i believe that's complicated area. ! why don't you try production hosting like heroku, openshift ?

Comment: yeah I have router to forward port but how can I redirect request to my computer's local ip address? can you give hint plz..

Comment: what router and what router brand you are using because each router have different method ...

Comment: i found few [link](http://www.tp-link.com/lb/article/?id=72) and this [link](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/tp-link-router-port-forwarding/) It may help you let me know...

Answer (score 2):

Run server with local host or your system IP like one of the below

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.6.7:8000

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

add hosts in **settings.py** to access from other system in network.

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','192.168.6.7']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working `DEBUG=True` mod in your Django project, you shouldn't need anything other than that (I assume you are not using port 80, it requires root access).

You must use `0.0.0.0` as host IP, it is a simple solution. And the command is:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. That's it.